# Exclude configurations from inherited configurations

Tags: maven, flyway

I use flyway to deploy db-changes to a db. I have a parent-pom where I have a configuration tag. In this configuration tag I use a `<table>`-tag to deal with the [change of the default table](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1848). Here is the plugin-configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${flyway-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
        <baselineOnMigrate>true</baselineOnMigrate>
        <table>schema_version</table>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>${ojdbc7.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Is there a way to exclude the `<table>`-tag in a pom that uses the parent-pom?

Comment: Overriding the `<table>` is not enough?

Comment: This would be a option, but I would like to get the default value. Maybe it would be also better to delete the `<table>`-tag in the parent-pom and specify it in the child-poms where I need the old value. But I'm still interested in a solution to exclude such a value.